# Selecting IDs/rows within a databrame, based on n-grams

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
ID       Text
12     Coolest fan we’ve ever seen.
12     SHARE this with anyone you know who can use this tip!
31     Time for a Royal Celebration! Save the date.
54     The way to a sports fan’s heart? Behind-the-scenes content from their favourite teams.
419    Start asking your questions now for tomorrow’s LIVE Q&A on careers you can do without going to university.
451    Save the date, we’re hosting a fabulous & fun meetup at Coffee Bar Bryant on 9/20. Stay tuned
```

I have used ngrams to analyse text and words/sentences frequency.

```
from nltk import ngrams

text=df.Text.tolist()

list_n=[]


for i in text:
    n_grams = ngrams(i.split(), 3)

    for grams in n_grams:
        list_n.append(grams)

list_n
```

Since I am interested in finding in which text a particular word/words sequence was used, I would need to create an association between text (i.e. `ID`)  and text with particular ngrams. 
For example: I am interested in finding texts which contains `"Save the date"`, i.e. `ID=31` and `ID=451`. 
To find the n-grams for one single word, I have been using this:

```
def ngram_filter(col, word, n):
    tokens = col.split()
    all_ngrams = ngrams(tokens, n)
    filtered_ngrams = [x for x in all_ngrams if word in x]
    return filtered_ngrams
```

However, I do not know how to find the `ID` associated to the text and how to select more words in the function above.

How could I do this? Any idea?

Please feel free to change tags, if you require. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with `ngrams`, but you could get what you want with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) like:

```
import re
txt = 'save the date'
print (f'The ngrams "{txt}" is in IDs: ',
       df.loc[df['Text'].str.contains(txt, flags=re.IGNORECASE), 'ID'].tolist())
The ngrams "save the date" is in IDs:  [31, 451]
```

Another option could be to do this, but the performance may not be good:

```
txt = 'save the date'

df_ = df.assign(ngrams=df.Text.str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '') #remove punctuation
                              .str.lower() # lower case
                              .str.split() #split over a whitespace
                              .apply(lambda x: list(ngrams(x, 3))))\
        .explode('ngrams') #create a row per ngram

print (df_.loc[df_['ngrams'].isin(ngrams(txt.lower().split(), 3))])
    ID                                               Text             ngrams
2   31       Time for a Royal Celebration! Save the date.  (save, the, date)
5  451  Save the date, we’re hosting a fabulous & fun ...  (save, the, date)
```

Comment: It is even better than the function that I was using! Thank you @Ben. T. How can I see also the  n-grams which contain only those words?

Comment: @Val glad it work for you. I assume `ngrams` has some advantage that this method would not allow, but this way is pretty easy :)

Comment: @Val but if you really want to work with `ngrams`, I assume you need to remove the punctuation, lower the case (although they might be a parameter for that, etc). Have a look atthe second option

Comment: Thank you, Ben. T. I was thinking if it would be better to remove punctuation as well, so thank you to anticipate